# Capture enter as an input (for int and char variables)

Tags: c

Let's suppose I have a structure called `books`, with both **string and int variables**.

I want to do the following:

1. Print the actual value stored in the variable.
2. Give the option to insert a new value.
3. If the user presses 'Enter', the value remains the same.

I tried to do it with `scanf`, but it is not able to receive an empty input. If it was, I could simply do:

```
printf("Current value: %d     New value: ",books.intVar);
scanf("%d",aux);
if (aux) {
     books.intVar = aux;
}
```

And something similar with the strings, but using `strcpy()` function to assign the new value.

I am pretty sure the solution to this problem is a combination of `gets()` and `sscanf()` but I don't see how should I use them to obtain the result I am looking for.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: Isn't `fgets()` strictly for files? I'm trying to read from keyboard input.

Comment: The keyboard input is read through the standard input file `stdin`, there is `fscanf()` too, `scanf()` is just `fscanf()` with file being `stdin`.

Comment: `fgets` is different from `gets` in that you can specify the stream from which it should read. `gets` only uses `stdin`. So, no, you can use `fgets` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgets()` instead, like this

```
char line[100];
int  value;
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
 {
    if (line[0] == '\n')
        handleEmptyLine();
    else
     {
        value = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
        fprintf(stdout, "New Value: %d\n", value);
        /* Do whatever you want with value */
     }
  }
```

While the same code would probably work with `gets()` it's a really bad and unnecessary thing to do, because you risk buffer overflow with `gets()` which has no way to limit input length, while `fgets()` does allow you to set a maximum value for the length of the destination buffer.

You should note that `fgets()` does read the `'\n'` character at the end of the input, which you can use conveniently in your case to check whether the line is empty, although it's not enough because an empty line could also be a bunch of white space characters, so the `line[0] == '\n'` test will only work if the user only presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key, hence it would be safer to do something like

```
char  buffer[100];
char *line;
int   value;

if ((line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) != NULL)
 {
    while ((line[0] != '\0') && (isspace((int) line[0]) != 0))
        line++;
    if (line[0] == '\0')
        handleEmptyLine();        
    else
     {
        value = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
        fprintf(stdout, "New Value: %d\n", value);
        /* Do whatever you want with value */
     }
  }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, but I think I found a significantly shorter way to achive the same. I posted it below. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`. And if you want to capture empty input, you can compare it to `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a much shorter and easier way to do the same thing @iharob suggests:

```
char aux[100];

// Sample data:
char name[100];
int number = 250;
strcpy(name,"Sample name");

// Interger case:
gets(aux);
sscanf(aux,"%d",number);

// String case:
gets(aux);
sscanf(aux,"%s",name);
```

When the program asks for an int or a string and we don'n provide it (pressing Enter instead), the value of the variables `number` and `name` won't change.

Comment: It's incorrect, `char aux(100)` and don't see what you mean? Also, `scanf("%d", number)` is wrong, it should be `if (sscanf(aux, "%d", &number) != 1) oopsItProblemGettingInput();` and don't use `gets()` it's a bad idea as I explained above, `gets()` is deprecated, use `fgets()`. Also, `sscanf("%s", name);` is wrong, so pretty much all the code is wrong. And this is not shorter, it's unsafe, becaue there is no error checking whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, sorry about the syntax errors, I just copied in a wrong version!

Comment: It's still bad to use `gets()` and also to ignore any possible problem that could happen during input, it's still unsafe instead of just shorter, i.e. If you skip error checking of course code will be short, also, don't use `gets()`, really don't use `gets()`, please don't use `gets()`, it's unsafe, and `strcpy()`, completely unneeded in this case, just `char name[] = "Sample Name"`, would do, and `sscanf()` when you can just `strtol()` also not making much sense. Are you forced to use `gets()` and `sscanf()`?

Comment: Altough I understand your explanations, I am in university and haven't seen the `strtol()` function yet, for example, so I can't use it. But I will replace `gets()` with `fgets()` and add the error checking (I have neither learned about this yet). Thanks!